# Feature selection list missing in editor Attribute window ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, editing

Using ArcGIS desktop 10.7

The Attributes window in Editor identifies the selected feature. However, it is no longer showing the feature selection list. (The drop down menu on the right side of the feature field which allows for changing the feature record to available feature types from the attribute table).

How do I revert the editor settings to get this feature selection menu back? The list of feature types is also missing in the Create Features window. Appears editing features went missing when I added a different layer into my map document and now missing in any map document.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the layer does not have any feature templates set.

Right click on the layer in the table of contents, then choose Editor -> Organize Feature Templates.

Work through the dialogue there (in most cases you can just hit "Finish") to create the feature templates.

Comment: Organize Feature Templates window - the layer I'm editing appears but the feature types are no where to be found. Clicking on 'New template from feature' just adds any feature names I've typed into the Attribute window in editor. Same thing when I click Finish in the Create New Templates Wizard.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for feature templates.

Comment: Had to first set the feature classes in symbology in the layer properties in order for the create features and attribute windows to recognize them